# How to encapsulate pandas plotting in a function?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I want to produce a number of graphs of a time series focusing on different periods.

Here is a small sample of my data:

```
data = {'CAT': {0: 1.0,
  1: 1.0,
  2: 1.0,
  3: 1.0,
  4: 1.0,
  5: 1.0,
  6: 1.0,
  7: 1.0,
  8: 1.0,
  9: 1.0,
  10: 1.0,
  11: 1.0},
 'month': {0: 201401,
  1: 201402,
  2: 201403,
  3: 201404,
  4: 201405,
  5: 201406,
  6: 201407,
  7: 201408,
  8: 201409,
  9: 201410,
  10: 201411,
  11: 201412},
 'year': {0: '2014',
  1: '2014',
  2: '2014',
  3: '2014',
  4: '2014',
  5: '2014',
  6: '2014',
  7: '2014',
  8: '2014',
  9: '2014',
  10: '2014',
  11: '2014'},
 'appl': {0: 0,
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: 0,
  5: 1,
  6: 2,
  7: 3,
  8: 0,
  9: 1,
  10: 2,
  11: 3}}
```

I am using this code

```
merged_df_2014 = sample[sample.year == '2014']
tmp = (sample.groupby(['CAT', pd.to_datetime(sample['month'], format='%Y%m')])
       ['appl'].mean().reset_index(name='probability of application')
      )
ax = sns.lineplot(data=tmp, x='month', y='probability of application', hue='CAT')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
```

to produce this graph:
[image]

I wanted to encapsulate this into a function:

```
def plot_year (df, y):
    df = df[df.year == y]
    tmp = (df.groupby(['CAT', pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%Y%m')])
       ['appl'].mean().reset_index(name='probability of application')
      )
    ax = sns.lineplot(data=tmp, x='month', y='probability of application', hue='CAT')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
    return ax
```

so that I can call it with different parameters so that I can plot a slightly different graph (e.g. by supplying a different year I should plot a different part of the time series).

but when I tried to call this function like this:

```
plot_year (sample, 2014)
```

or this

```
ax = plot_year (sample, 2014)
```

I am getting an empty plot with a wrong period on the x axis:

[image]

How can I properly encapsulate and call this graphing function so that I can use the same code with different parameters to produce different graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the script uses the year as a string `"2014"`. In the function, you're using the numerical form`2014`.

Change your function to convert the year to a string:

```
def plot_year (df, y):
    df = df[df.year == str(y)]
    tmp = (df.groupby(['CAT', pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%Y%m')])
       ['appl'].mean().reset_index(name='probability of application')
      )
    ax = sns.lineplot(data=tmp, x='month', y='probability of application', hue='CAT')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
    return ax
```